# Python: Building a Bar Chart in Tkinter with Data From an SQlite3 Database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, tkinter-canvas, python-3.6

Before I start I am new to stack overflow so I apologize if my question is poorly formatted. Also this is for an A-level school project for my school library and aims to help with the management of the library. I have created a table containing data about students previous loans named 'pastLoans'([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOYPg.png) ), I need a way of finding out which books are most popular among library users and represent the findings on a bar chart. To do this I created an SQL command that counts the number of times a book title appears from the 'book' column of the 'pastLoans' table, currently I have 2 books in there ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLK2q.png)).

Due to the nature of Tk.canvas bar charts only except integers as data respectively, so I need to find a way of splitting up the name of the book and the amount of times it occurs in the table, using the amount of times it has occurred as the data to be displayed on the barchart, and the name of the book as the labels on the X Axis.

Currently I have coded the SQL command to pull the data I need from the table containing data about the past loans using the 'COUNT' function in SQLite3, additionally I have coded the frame for the bar chart and have tested it works with sample data from a list e.g [1,2,3,4,5,..]

Please note the bar chart successfully displays on Tkinter with the correct data values, unfortunately I cannot add a picture of the result since I do not have enough rep.

My code looks like this:

```
    command = ("SELECT book,COUNT(book) AS cnt FROM pastLoans GROUP BY 
    book ORDER BY cnt DESC;")

    c.execute(command)
    result = c.fetchall()
    print (result)                            
    """This is the code for pulling the book name and amount of books 
    from the "pastLoans" as well as the book name, the result is this:

    >>> [('Book', 1), ('Harry Potter', 1)]


    This is my bar chart frame:"""

    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #The data used here is sample data.

    g_width = 900  # Define it's width
    g_height = 400  # Define it's height
    g = tk.Canvas(self, width=g_width, height=g_height)
    g.grid()

    # The variables below size the bar graph
    y_stretch = 15  # The highest y = max_data_value * y_stretch
    y_gap = 20  # The gap between lower canvas edge and x axis
    x_stretch = 10  # Stretch x wide enough to fit the variables
    x_width = 20  # The width of the x-axis
    x_gap = 20  # The gap between left canvas edge and y axis

    for x, y in enumerate(data):

        # coordinates of each bar

        # Bottom left coordinate
        x0 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_gap

        # Top left coordinates
        y0 = g_height - (y * y_stretch + y_gap)

        # Bottom right coordinates
        x1 = x * x_stretch + x * x_width + x_width + x_gap

        # Top right coordinates
        y1 = g_height - y_gap

        # Draw the bar
        g.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="red")

        # Put the y value above the bar
        g.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor=tk.SW, text=str(y))
```

Comment: I don't quite get your problem. It seems that you want to add the title of the books instead of `str(y)`, but you don't know how to iterate over the entries in result.

Comment: I want to be able to separate the name of the book (a string) and the amount of times the book occurs (integer) and plot the name of the book and the X axis and the amount of times the book occur on the Y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already done all of the work to get tkinter display the bars and some text above it you just have to iterate over `result` instead of `data`:

```
# Sort so that the most popular book is on the left
result.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)

for x, (name, y) in enumerate(result):
   ...

   # Put the name above the bar
   g.create_text(x0 + 2, y0, anchor=tk.SW, text=name)
```

You may have to vary the `x_stretch` variable, so that the text does not overlap.